# What is the meaning of the ==<> operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

Looking into some code of a colleague of mine, I came accross the following:

```
friend bool operator==<>(ValueIter<Type> const &rhs, ValueIter<Type> const &lhs);
```

It is declared in  a template class:

```
template<typename Type>
class ValueIter: public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Type>
```

Can someone tell me what the `==<>` symbol indicates? I expect it has something to with the `!=` operator.

Comment: What is the immediately preceding line of code? And generally what is the context of this? This is related to templates.

Comment: In a vacuum, it means a syntax error.

Comment: Clearly it is the equal to, less than or greater than operator.  It returns false on incomparibles.  ;)

Comment: What does the symbol `==<>` indicates? IMO it indicates how many WTFs could have been prevented if people wouldn't try to "save" that one byte in the source code by omitting an "unnecessary" space.

Comment: @Barry: Isn't that true of most things?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It looks like two, the `operator==` that is a full template instantiation or specialisation `<>`.

I've seen only a few like this in the wild though.

Given the `friend`, the class is probably [befriending the template operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators).

---

If you are getting linker errors with it, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35891188/3747990) for why.

Comment: Reminds me of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/3747990) on operator `-->`.

Comment: It indeed is a template for the operator==. I have seen this before template classes. When one removes the <> you will get an error indicating that the function is a non-template function.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is incomplete.

Presumably, in some context within the code you are examining, there is a templated `operator==()` function.

Then within some class, a particular specialisation of that templated `operator==()` is being declared as a `friend`.

Without context that you haven't given (i.e. of the preceding template definition, or of the enclosing class definition) it is not possible to give a more specific answer.   There are too many possibilities for what the template or relevant specialisations are.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
template <typename T> class ValueIter;

template <typename T> 
bool operator==(ValueIter<T> const &rhs, ValueIter<T> const &lhs);
```

Inside `template <typename T> class ValueIter`

- `friend bool operator==(ValueIter const &rhs, ValueIter const &lhs);`
  and `friend bool operator==(ValueIter<T> const &rhs, ValueIter<T> const &lhs);`
  add friendship to a non template operator.
- `friend bool operator==<>(ValueIter const &rhs, ValueIter const &lhs);`,
  `friend bool operator==<>(ValueIter<T> const &rhs, ValueIter<T> const`
  `friend bool operator==<T>(ValueIter const &rhs, ValueIter const &lhs);`,
  `friend bool operator==<T>(ValueIter<T> const &rhs, ValueIter<T> const`
  add friendship to the template operator (just for the type with match `T`)
- `template <typename U> friend bool operator==(ValueIter<U> const &rhs, ValueIter<U> const &lhs);` add friendship to the template operator (for any type `U` (which may differ of `T`))

`==<>` is used in the second point and is really `== <>`.